# Dockerfile setting ENV in different file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which builds a Rails app. The Rails app is dependent upon 20+ environment variables. I would like to extract the setting of these variables away from the original Dockerfile into a different file which is then called by the Dockerfile.

**Current implementation**

```
# Dockerfile
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

ENV SECRET_KEY1=abcdef
ENV MY_URL=CRAZYURL
ENV MY_DB=tisMyDB
# .... + 20 lines of setting
ENV LAST_ENV=FinallyItsOver
```

Obviously this is cumbersome to a supposedly neatly organized Dockerfile

**Seeking something like:**

```
# Dockerfile
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

config/set_envs
```

+

```
# config/set_envs
ENV SECRET_KEY1=abcdef
# ...
ENV LAST_ENV=FinallyItsOver
```

Comment: I am completely open to answers such as "this is why you're thinking is wrong, and this is what you need to learn/do instead"

Comment: Just a sidenote, if you have secrets, putting them in a file is not secure, `docker inspect` and other methods will display them. Adrian Mouat had offered some better solutions in a post

Comment: Adrian suggest using either  etcd, Vault or Keywhiz. see http://container-solutions.com/content/uploads/2015/06/15.06.15_DockerCheatSheet_A2.pdf